# add a row to query in MS-ACCESS SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to add to the following query:

```
    strSQL = "SELECT  fldName, blkName, CDbl(fldValue) " & _
        "FROM dbSecurities2 as S " & _
        "WHERE " & _
        "S.isin='" & Code & "' " & _
        "AND " & _
        "S.fldName='" & fldName & "' "
```

A row that makes the sum of the fldValue like:

```
    strSQL = "SELECT  fldName, blkName, CDbl(fldValue) " & _
        "FROM dbSecurities2 as S " & _
        "UNION " & _
        "SELECT Sum(fldValue) AS fldValue " & _
        "WHERE " & _
        "S.isin='" & Code & "' " & _
        "AND " & _
        "S.fldName='" & fldName & "' "
```

the error is:

> Run -time error '3141'. The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect

Comment: Define "doesn't work" ... is there an error? If so, what is the error? Part of the trouble is likely because the union select does not have a `FROM` clause _and_ is not querying the same number of columns.

Comment: You're right the error is Run -time error '3141'. The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect

Comment: Can you add a small data example to the question (from the first query), along with an example of the desired output? Best to add this info as text and not as pictures.

Answer (score 1):

I found this is working:

```
   strSQL = "SELECT fldName, blkName, CDbl(fldValue) " & _
        "FROM dbSecurities2 as S " & _
        "WHERE " & _
        "S.isin='" & Code & "' " & _
        "AND " & _
        "S.fldName='" & fldName & "' " & _
        "UNION " & _
        "SELECT '' AS fldName, 'Total' AS Total, Sum(CDbl(fldValue)) " & _
        "FROM dbSecurities2 AS B " & _
        "WHERE " & _
        "B.isin='" & Code & "' " & _
        "AND " & _
        "B.fldName='" & fldName & "' "
```

Answer (score 0):

This should run as expected:

```vb
    strSQL = "SELECT fldName, blkName, CDbl(fldValue) " & _
        "FROM dbSecurities2 AS S " & _
        "WHERE " & _
        "S.isin='" & Code & "' " & _
        "AND " & _
        "S.fldName='" & fldName & "' " & _
        "UNION ALL " & _
        "SELECT TOP 1 "", "Total", Sum(CDbl(fldValue)) " & _
        "FROM dbSecurities2"
```

If you have *Null* values, use *Nz*:

```vb
    strSQL = "SELECT fldName, blkName, CDbl(Nz(fldValue, 0)) " & _
        "FROM dbSecurities2 AS S " & _
        "WHERE " & _
        "S.isin='" & Code & "' " & _
        "AND " & _
        "S.fldName='" & fldName & "' " & _
        "UNION ALL " & _
        "SELECT TOP 1 "", "Total", Sum(CDbl(Nz(fldValue, 0))) " & _
        "FROM dbSecurities2"
```

Comment: Hi Gustav, I adjusted your expression in the second SELECT as :"SELECT top 1 '' as fldName, 'Total' as blkName, Sum(CDbl(fldValue))" & _   But I get an get the error Data type mismatch in criteria expression... any Idea why?

Comment: instead "SELECT top 1 '' as fldName, 'Total' as blkName, fldValue " & _ works and give me an empty line as Total. it seems that the problem is the Sum but I cannot figure out why...

Comment: _ I get an get the error Data type mismatch in criteria expression... any Idea why?_ Sure. You corrected the correct SQL to invalid SQL. If you have _Null_ values, _CDbl_ will fail; see extended answer, please.

Comment: I still have the same error: Data type mismatch in criteria expression. see extended answer